# How can I create a vector from a matrix using specified colums from each row without looping in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, indexing

Say I have a matrix of shape (N,d) and a vector of size N which says which column in the matrix is of relevance to a given row. How can I return the vector of size N which is given by the values in the matrix and the relevant column?

For example:

```
M = [[ 2, 4, 1, 8],
    [3, 5, 7, 1],
    [2, 5, 3, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 4]]
V = [2, 1, 0, 1]
```

I tried something like:

```
M[:,V]
```

but this returns a matrix which is NXN

Is there a simple way to format this which does not involve writing a for-loop so that I could get the following vector:

```
V' = [1,5,2,2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.arange(len(V))` for indexing the row numbers and `V` for columns:

```
In [110]: M = [[ 2, 4, 1, 8],
   .....:     [3, 5, 7, 1],
   .....:     [2, 5, 3, 9],
   .....:     [1, 2, 3, 4]]

In [111]: V = [2, 1, 0, 1]

In [112]: 

In [112]: M = np.array(M)

In [113]: M[np.arange(len(V)),V]
Out[113]: array([1, 5, 2, 2])
```